# Diamond operator for return value

Tags: java, generics

Does this work with `Java 7`? (I only have Java 6 installed.)

```
List<> customers = service.getCustomers(); // returns List<Customer>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use this as a good reason to update your Java version.

Answer (score 5):

No, the diamond is used to avoid the boilerplate code generated due to declaring twice the generics:

Java 6:

```
List<List<String>> myList= new ArrayList<List<String>>()
```

Java 7 equivalent code:

```
 List<List<String>> myList = new ArrayList<>() 
 //the generic is declared once
```

but in your example the diamond operator has no "original generic" declaration to assume the correct type, so it won't compile.

Answer (score 3):

No, its a compile time error.

> Incorrect number of arguments for type List; it cannot be
>   parameterized with arguments <>